# Performance issues with formhandler in TYPO3 6.2

Tags: performance, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using the extension *formhandler* on a website. When a user fills in the form and submits he will get an email with a confirmations link.
The problem is the following:
When the user clicks on the confirmation link, it takes up to 15 seconds for TYPO3 to show either the "success" or the "error" page.

TYPO3 cache is enabled, varnish is for this pages disabled (of course) and now I don't know what I could do to improve the loading time.

Comment: Are other pages slow, too? Does the Frontend Admin-Panel say the Caching is enabled? What PHP version do you use? Where is your page hosted?

Comment: No, all other pages are quite quick (<1s load time). AdmPanel says caching is enabled.
We suppose it's a result of our "web performance optimization". Because our customer wants a good score in Googles PageSpeed Insights (we reached 100/100) but since then, some pages are f**king slow -.-
Sometimes...I really hate customers xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case somebody encounters a similar problem:
The issue was something in the *formhandler*-extension itself.
Whyever, *formandler* performed a "SHOW TABLE STATUS" on all tables, when trying to validate the AuthCode. This query took about 8 seconds.
I changed the code a bit and now the page loads in less than 3 seconds.